# Add jar file to local repository (linux server)

Tags: java, linux, maven

I created a "lib" folder in my project

**~\test2000\lib\ls-client.jar**

[image]

Then, I added a jar file to this folder

Now I want to call him in the project, I did this with the following code, In my system right.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightstreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ls-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/ls-client.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

But when I transfer the program to the Linux server

There's an error saying that it can not read jarFile

I think I do not enter **groupId** and **artifactId**!!!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is the wrong path : "com.lightstreamer.ls-client" !!!,

Right path : test2000\lib\ls-client.jar. But I do not know how to get the groupId and artifactId in the file jar!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1:** 
Download the "**ls-client**", extract it and copy the ls-client.jar to somewhere else, for example, c drive. Issue following command :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\\test2000\lib\ls-client.jar -DgroupId=com.lightstreamer 
-DartifactId=ls-client -Dversion=2.5.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

**step 2:**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightstreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>ls-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```